# How to customize intentions in PyCharm (e.g. modify "After" code)

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, pycharm, python-sphinx

PyCharm (and the other IntelliJ IDEs) have the idea of [intention actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-intention-actions.html). One that I want to customize is the "Insert documentation string stub" so that it includes type annotations. I can't type in the After section or find a menu that allows me to modify it at all - is that possible? If not, is there another plugin or something that will allow such a modification?

[image: Preferences window for intentions]

Answer (score 1):

You can not customize intentions. But you may use Live Templates, they are very customizable: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/live-templates.html